Customize Allure Report using --single-file Option
Currently I have an automation framework that is running in WDIO using the --single-file option because I need to be able send the report out.
Here's my command line that is generating the report
allure generate ./reports/allure-results --clean --single-file ./reports/allure-results && allure open
I'd like to be able to gen the report with our corporate logo and to be able to change the title. I can see where this is possible without the single file option flag, but the --single-file option doesn't have the structure needed to do so (plugins directory to add the custom-logo-plugin). Is this possible when creating a single file report? I'm new to allure (and WDIO) so if more information is needed I'll get right at getting that
